# Getting "Repositroy test has failed" error while cloning repository from Gitlab in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, linker-errors, gitlab

I will like to clone my android code from gitlab repository in Android Studio 0.8.1.I checked into VCS >> Checked out from Version Control >> Git >> Added HTTP url here.It prompts me that "Repositroy test has failed".Kindly help me to sort out the issue.I have checked the plugins as well.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it work via CLI or some other GUI tool? Does it work via `git@git...` url?

Comment: You sure you have installed Git on your system?

Comment: Thanks Marius and gnuanu,solution given be Sree below worked..

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to download and install git from http://git-scm.com/downloads

Then you need to track the git.exe on AndroidStudio:

- Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Version Control</kbd> > <kbd>VCSs</kbd> > <kbd>Git</kbd> > <kbd>Path to Git executable</kbd>
- Select (or type) executable path, eg: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe`

**If you installed GitHub Desktop for Windows**

In case you have GitHub Desktop for Windows, `git.exe` will be found at `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565zz218z5214zzz0e854zzza28\cmd`.

Comment: Why can't it auto-scan this file, and if not found, ask to download... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: /usr/bin/git for OS X 10.9.5 & XCode 6.1

Answer (score 3):

If you Installed git from http://git-scm.com/downloads and also sett the correct path and still get an error maybe you sit behind a Proxy, in this case you have to add the Proxy to the git. This is Possible in the gitconfig. Wich should be avaiable in :\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc  if you used the standard path for installation.

Comment: I still have the problem like that i did what sree said but still have the same problem,can u please give me some solution for that

Comment: Perfect answer. But is there any provision to logout second user from studio & add another one?

Answer (score 2):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 (this applies to other versions as well) and all I needed to do was to install git from apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

This means Android Studio was trying to execute git command but it could not be recognized so if you have git installed then try to execute git from terminal and if not recognized then you should configure paths to git executable. That was it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Sree's answer, I was getting this error even after installing Git, but the problem is that I didn't install it to the default installation folder.

After choosing the right path and folder in the VCS settings tab, it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the **HTTP URL** in browser, that my collaborator sent me:

> https://github.com/mansonpeter/GoUpApp/invitations

for download and join the developing team, there was an **accept button**, after accepting hopefully the error gone, repository test was successful and I got the project in android studio. before this I had tried all the suggestion on this page and non of them was efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the "Clone git repositories using SSH".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Linux, At first check you have the appropriate certification to know this you can clone the repository in terminal if you get error similar this

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://YourDomainName/Project/GitRepository/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

then open your domain in browser and click on lock in the left of url go to detail and press export to save the certification and finally copy the content of the file and pase it into

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

For me this solution for the issue worked.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Settings > Version Control > Git` and set `SSH Executable` to "Native" instead of "Built-in". Then restart your IDE for settings to apply.

Worked for me in all jetbrains IDEs.