# Error trying to clone git repository in Visual Studio Team Services from Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, azure-devops

I have been using the git features of Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) for a while with my .NET projects and now want to start using them with my android projects.

https://MyVsoAccount.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/My%20Project%20Name

When I click the test button it says "Repository test has failed". Am I using the wrong git repository URL for my Team Services project?

Comment: Just to confirm, that is not the actual URL you are using, right?

Comment: No, hehe, I am swapping out "MyVsoAccount" for my actual one. and "My%20Project%20Name" for my actual name. My project actually does have spaces in its name so it has the "%20" in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625335/getting-repositroy-test-has-failed-error-while-cloning-repository-from-gitlab). You need to make sure git is installed on your machine, and that Android Studio knows where the git executable is.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate instead of posting an answer.