# Intellij 15 + Github - cannot clone repository, getting "Repository Test has Failed" error

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have Intellij 15 and a Github account, and I'm trying to unite the two.  I went into settings -> Version Control, and added Github with the Host and username and password.  When I click "Test" - it works.

I also have installed the GitHub executable, and added it to the settings as well, and that test was successful as well.

Then I go to my project, select VCS from the top menu, then go to "Checkout from Version Control" ---> "GitHub".  It gives me a "Clone Repository Dialog".

This is when things get interesting.  In that dialog, it shows "Git Repository URL" as "-------------------------------" - yes, a whole bunch of dashes, and the error at the bottom is "Repository URL is a malformed URL or non-existent directory"...  Now - I have not found any settings where I can specify it outside of this dialog box, so I don't know where it's taking the URL from...

[image: Initial error on dialog popup]

I enter the correct URL, parent directory, and Directory Name...  Then I click on "Test".  And it gives me "Repository test has failed".  Actually, it gives me that same error regardless of what's in the "Git Repository URL" from that point on - even when I put a bunch of gibberish - it still gives the Test Has failed error.

[image: The error message I get after all subsequent test attempts, regardless of what is actually in the Git Repository URL field]

I have also tried going to "Checkout from Version Control" ---> "Git" - with same results.

I have looked online at different forums and tutorials, and nothing seems to help.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Setup pics - tests successful in the setup:
[image: Git Setup (exe location)]

[image: GitHub setup (host, uname/pass)]

Comment: Can you put screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Added screenshots to the original post

Answer (score 4):

try to change SSH executable from Build-in to Native.

Comment: Thank you. This was the issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time :-)

Answer (score 3):

in my case, after I un-check "clone git repositories using SSH" checkbox from settings/Version Control/github; it works on clone task.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Setting->Version Control->GitHub
check"Clone git repositories using ssh"

Comment: Add some comments to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

for

```
Repository test has failed
```

follow my answer in the [git test error in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625335/getting-repositroy-test-has-failed-error-while-cloning-repository-from-gitlab)

Answer (score 1):

Removing my other id from keychain fixed it for me. So make sure you have just one git id there

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue until I set the <kbd>SSH-executable</kbd> option to use `Built-in` SSH (just like you have). This immediately solved my problem and I wasn't getting the error anymore.

---

Further options I am using include:

- I have opted to use token authentication rather than a password
- I am using the Windows Setup for git rather than a portable setup
  [image]
- And the path to git is set as `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

Apart from these 3 options, my settings look exactly like yours. I am running windows 10 64bit and my version of IntelliJ is `2016.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issues with IntelliJ and I tried following:

To Solve this problem, Browse to Git location through a web browser:

[Click on Clone button i.e. 2nd menu button on left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbo5f.png)

Now click the fully qualified link mentioned in the HTTP text box as below:

[Fully qualified link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B28fK.png)

Now copy the above copied link to Clone Repository window in IntelliJ and try again. Test connection and It should be successful

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cmd

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

If nothing works after

```
 Checking Accept non trusted certificates



UnChecking "clone git repositories using SSH" checkbox
```