# Can't clone from GitHub in AndroidStudio 2.1 Beta

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Git is installed:
[image]

Have access to GitHub with my account

[image]

**But can't clone a repository from the list:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Today is available AndroidStudio 2.1 Beta 2
**The issue is resolved**, but it works only with http. 
**SSH doesn't work**

THIS dialog shows 3 times. and then error:
*Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.*
[image]

Android studio log:

```
2016-04-15 13:03:39,507 [5583156]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,671 [5585320]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - java.io.IOException: Authentication failed: 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,671 [5585320]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:298) 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,672 [5585321]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:172) 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,672 [5585321]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137) 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,681 [5585330]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,681 [5585330]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
2016-04-15 13:03:41,681 [5585330]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - and the repository exists.
```

But repository exists and ssh key is added, I have access rights. I previous version it works.

Comment: Please have a look at this [Stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611289/intellij-15-github-cannot-clone-repository-getting-repository-test-has-fai)

Comment: @AswinPJ I set the SSH-executable option to use Built-in, but problem is not solved

Comment: Does Android Studio show any other detailed errors in the console below?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.... I'm seeing it also when I try to Push/Pull from Android Studio.  The only workaround that I have found so far is to go back to Android Studio 2.0

Comment: I have submitted an issue with Android Studio https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206946 (I'm assuming this issue is related)

Comment: @JeffCampbell on another comp I just update git to 2.8.1.0..now it works

Comment: @NickUnuchek on MacOS X there's no git 2.8.1.0 available on the official site

Answer (score 0):

this method work for me.

Just simply use git-bash to create public key that store in ~/.ssh

then download [source tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and open it

1) go to tool

2) click on 'create or Import SSH keys'

3)go to Conversation

4) go to ~/.ssh directory

5) select id_rse file

this wil show you the public key copy it and paste int your bitbucket.org/ssh-key 
 and done.