# Android Studio - Failed to create github repo

Tags: java, android-studio, github

[image]

I've installed github properly and am able to login from Android Studio, but I get this error message. What could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure your **git** path is set in studio setting. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24625373/2949612

Answer (score 7):

Probably, you use line separator in your description. This will cause such an error. If you write all your description at same line, you will go through the commit process.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i am sure the error log in your case is the same to what it was in my case (see the pic). the problem is we should not use the new line or [ENTER KEY] in the description of your repository,just write everything in the same line.[image: the image is error log of the same problem in android studio]

Answer (score 0):

You should check Git integration configuration in Android Studio

[image]

press <kbd>Test</kbd> button for testing.

I am also using Android Studio, I just push a new Android project to GitHub successful.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I was trying to create a repo with a name that already existed in my account.

Answer (score 0):

This probably because you used some symbols in your description, I removed the commas, the new lines and the dots then it saved it.